# postgresql получить список отключенных внешних ключей

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, sql-server

Всем привет! Собственно как поучить список всех отключенных внешних ключей по всем таблицам?
К примеру в MSSQL это делается так:
`select * from sys.foreign_keys where is_disabled=1`

UPD: Решение
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718314/postgresql-get-list-of-disabled-foreign-keys

Comment: Вариант решения который мне подошел лежит по ссылке:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718314/postgresql-get-list-of-disabled-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1):

В Postgresql можно получить список отключенных внешних ключей для всех таблиц, используя системный каталог информации `pg_constraint`

```
SELECT conname, conrelid::regclass, confrelid::regclass
FROM pg_constraint
WHERE contype = 'f' AND convalidated = false;
```

Этот запрос выбирает имя внешнего ключа (conname), имя таблицы, содержащей внешний ключ (conrelid::regclass), и имя связанной таблицы (confrelid::regclass) для всех внешних ключей (contype = 'f') в базе данных, которые не прошли проверку на соответствие (convalidated = false), то есть являются отключенными.

Comment: вы ошиблись с трактовкой convalidated, not valid constraint всё равно проверяется для всех записываемых/изменяемых строк. Не обещает, что все уже существующие строки соответствуют этому constraint, но уже гарантирует, что новых появляться уже не будет.

Answer (score 1):

В postgresql нет понятия отключенного foreign key. Foreign key или есть или его нет.

---

Технически, суперпользователь может обойти исполнение FK, отключив выполнение системных триггеров: из-за того, что foreign key на уровне реализации в postgresql обеспечивается набором системных триггеров. Это может быть сделано через ALTER TABLE для таблицы (смотрите возможные состояния [`pg_trigger.tgenabled`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html)) либо настройкой сессии `session_replication_role`